# Mechanics of WHERE EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, exists

Can anyone tell me why these two queries don't return the same number of rows ?

```
SELECT ProductSubcategoryID AS ProdSubID
FROM Production.Product
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Production.Product 
    WHERE Weight IS NOT NULL 
)
```

```
SELECT ProductSubcategoryID AS ProdSubID
FROM Production.Product
WHERE Weight IS NOT NULL
```

Production.Product can be found in AdventureWorks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not the same predicates in the where clause.

The first query will return every `ProductSubcategoryID` in `Production.Product` as long as there is at least one record where `Weight` is not `null`,

while the second query will return every `ProductSubcategoryID` in `Production.Product` where in the same row, the `Weight` is not `null`.

For the queries to be equivalent, the subquery in the first one must be correlated to outer query - you do that like this:

```
SELECT ProductSubcategoryID AS ProdSubID
FROM Production.Product As p0
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Production.Product As p1
    WHERE p1.<row identifier> = p0.<row identifier>
    AND Weight IS NOT NULL )
```

Where `<row identifier>` means a value (or set of values) that is unique for each row in the table.